# composer update "process killed"

Tags: process, composer-php, dreamhost

I tried to execute:

```
composer.phar update
```

And received:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in phar:///home/xxxxxxx/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 123

The *xxxxxxx* is the user.

And then I tried to execute:

```
php -d memory_limit=256M ~/bin/composer.phar update
```

And:

```
php -d memory_limit=512M ~/bin/composer.phar update
```

Then I received this:

> Yikes! One of your processes (php, pid 14331) was just killed for excessive resource usage.
>   Please contact DreamHost Support for details.**

How can I execute composer update on Dreamhost shared host? Can someone who had experienced this situation could help me please?

The context: Laravel 4

Comment: beware, dreamhost shared host alow to install composer, but the host is too slow to run "composer update". No make sense it, you can install but impossible to use.

Comment: the response from Dreamhost: "I'm afraid that it may be best to look into using our VPS service.  The processes coming from your account are too high to stay on our shared plan.  Here's a link with information on our VPS service if needed."

the end of story: the command "composer update" its impossible to use in dreamhost shared host because the server is too slow and limited, bad host.

Comment: I was able to install Laravel 4 two months ago using composer... but now I retried and process got killed...

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo Same here, this was definately working for me in October because I used the shared hosting to develop a site in Laravel. I just tried now and I get the same problem as OP.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Run the `composer update` command on your development machine, which generates the `composer.lock` file for you. Upload that `composer.lock` file and on the shared host just run `composer install`. This will use a lot less memory!

Comment: This could solve the issue, and be correct to live but don't actually explain why its failing and that shouldn't!

Comment: working..upload local composer.lock file on server and run composer install command

Answer (score 2):

It happens for a lack of memory of your server.

1. You can install the package in your local machine
2. Then replace your server **composer.lock** file with the local's composer.lock file
   (or push the composer.lock file from local and pull the composer.lock file in the server)
3. Then go to the terminal and run **composer update** or **composer install**.